# How to get which activities are running in application in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

As I googled, I came across this code.

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService( ctx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
    int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
    CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
    int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
    String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
}
```

This tells me how many tasks are running and also the number of activities in a task.

I am currently developing an app and want to keep track of which activities are still active in my own application.
Basically I want to get the contents of int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to record all activities info in your own application. and you can query them whenever you want in any of your activity.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addActivityName(String name) {
        mNames.add(name);
    }

    public void removeActivityName(String name) {
        mNames.remove(name);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getActivityNames() {
        return mNames;
    }
}
```